# Turned on Assistive Touch, now have blue circle dancing around the screen

Tags: iphone

I turned on Assistive Touch (under General options, Accessibility) on my iPhone 4, ios 6.1.3 (10B329).  This seemed to work for a bit, but I've just come back to my phone and there's now a blue circle dancing around the screen.  It seems to be taking the focus so it's not responding to my touches and I can't unlock the screen . . . help!

Comment: Are you looking to teach yourself how assistive touch works or just that you could plug the iPhone into a computer where it syncs and turn off the feature using iTunes?

Comment: Oh, didn't realise you could turn off the feature in iTunes, will try that now, thanks!  (I originally enabled the feature because the Home button on the phone is a little temperamental but given this experience I don't think Assistive Touch is the answer.)

Comment: Both AT and Voiceover have the capability to really confuse people when someone familiar with how they work isn't around to help assist. Please go ahead and answer your own question if you manage to solve it ;-) We love when an answer is provided - even if it took comments and some testing to arrive at them.

Comment: Well, as I was preparing to connect my iPhone to my Mac and turn off Assistive Touch in iTunes, the dancing blue circle disappeared . . . . wierd.